# How to wait for all images are loaded from loadfromjson to canvas in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to hide the loader when all images are loaded on canvas. Currently, what happens it's not waiting for images loaded on canvas. Help is appreciated.

```
loader.show();
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
   loader.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method support a callback, that you are using with `canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)`
Instead of calling that function call your own function to render and hide the loader.

```
loader.show();
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, function() {
   canvas.renderAll();
   loader.hide();
});
```

The third function is used only to process each object after initialization and gets called once per object.

Comment: Thanks, it's working I modify the function according to your suggestion. and I loop through JSON before loadfromjson for custom operation.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromDatalessJSON) you can read that the third function is called

> after each fabric object created.

So it will hide the loader when the first image will be loaded.

You can use counter inside the body of `function(o, object)` and check if the counter achieved a number of expected images to show, and then hide the loader.

Comment: ...and where is he supposed to check the counter?

Comment: He can define counter in scope when `loader.show` is executed and check it in the body of the third argument of  `loadFromJSON`. But when I read your answer I think is better.

Comment: Well, that should do in most cases, but I think on very very rare occasions it can give the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Promise.all(), something like:

```
function loadImg(json){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
         resolve();
      })
   });
}
```

Then:

```
loader.show();
Promise.all(jsonArr.map(loadImg)).then(loader.hide);
```

I am unable to give you a definite answer due to some ambiguity, but it should be along this line.